# Does Webkit render 8bit PNGs correctly

Tags: webkit, png

I've come across a weird problem whilst trying to optimise the following image:

[image]

It should have a little shadow down each of the left and right hand sides. However, in webkit (tried mac safari and chrome) the right hand edge loses its little shadow entirely. I've used multiple utilities to create the image and even tried copying a flipped version of the left hand side to the right, all to no avail.

Have I generated the png incorrectly or does webkit have a problem? It looks as it should in Firefox, IE etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may have been a bug with the WebKit rendering engine, but it appears to render correctly now.